# Decimal to Binary Converter in Java

Tags: java, binary, decimal, converters

I need to make a decimal to binary converter in Java. I can't use Integer.toBinaryString() and every answer I've seen uses that. I need to actually make the algorithm. I want to keep the input an int and the output a String because if I change that the rest of the program this is from gets messed up. If you can, keep it pretty basic. This is what I've ended up with after hours of drafting and scrapping and there's many things wrong with it, like it doesn't even put together a binary number. Please, please help, I'm so confused and my brain is a mess.

```
public static String decToBin(int dec)
  {
    String bin = "";
    int exp = 0;

    for(int expLevel = 0; Math.pow(2, expLevel) <= dec; expLevel++)
    {
      if(dec - Math.pow(2, expLevel) >= 0)
      {
        dec -= Math.pow(2, expLevel-1);
      }
    }
    return bin;
  }
```

Comment: There is no decimal here. The input is already binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to review your math notes. Here's a good explanation of the basic algorithm: [How to Convert from Decimal to Binary](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary).

If you check the provided link, you will see that you just need to get the remainder of the divisions of the number divided by 2. As a brief algorithm:

```
int n <- user input (or other source)
String binaryForm <- empty string
while (n > 0) {
    int res <- n % 2;
    n <- n / 2;
    binaryForm <- res + binaryForm
}
```

Comment: I've overthought this so much I couldn't even tell you what two plus two is. Thanks, that cleared it up. However I don't know how to use that reverse function. I checked the Java API and there's no reverse() function in the String class, where do I find it?

Comment: It was a pseudocode to tell you to reverse a String. By the way, you can reverse a `String` using [`StringBuilder#reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()).

Comment: I rewrote what I had with what you said in mind. Somehow it magically works perfectly without the need to reverse it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Two rather obvious things:

- You are not changing `bin` anywhere after declaring (and `exp` is not used either).
- The condition in `if(dec - Math.pow(2, expLevel) >= 0)` is equivalent to the loop invariant, thus always true.

This approach can be made to work, but the loop has to go the other way, i.e. from the higher powers of two to the lower ones (which means you first have to find the highest power of two smaller than the input, unless you are fine with leading zeros). Also, it may help to avoid reassigning the method parameter (`dec`).

Answer (score 0):

You can shift the argument by 1 bit and add it up to a string. At the end you can reverse it, like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(decToBin(0));
        System.out.println(decToBin(1));
        System.out.println(decToBin(2));
        System.out.println(decToBin(127));
    }

    public static String decToBin(int dec) {
        if (dec == 0) {
            return "0"; // special case
        }

        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int current = dec;

        while (current != 0) {
            result.append(current & 0x1);
            current = current >> 1;
        }

        return result.reverse().toString();
    }
}
```

And a [fiddle](http://ideone.com/tx4L0F) for it.
It works for positive integers though.

Comment: We're still too new to know what stuff like >> or StringBuilder are so even if I used this my teacher would've called me out on using StackOverflow.

Comment: I guess you can replace `StringBuilder` with `String` concatenation and shifting with division by 2.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DecimalToBinary {

public String toBinary(int n) {
   if (n == 0) {
       return "0";
   }
   String binary = "";
   while (n > 0) {
       int rem = n % 2;
       binary = rem + binary;
       n = n / 2;
   }
   return binary;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
   int decimal = scanner.nextInt();
   DecimalToBinary decimalToBinary = new DecimalToBinary();
   String binary = decimalToBinary.toBinary(decimal);
   System.out.println("The binary representation is " + binary);

}
}
```

Comment: Maybe add a little text.

Comment: `Scanner.nextInt()` converts decimal to binary. The rest of this does something else.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.